# Windows 7 boot loop on Preparing To Configure Windows

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a laptop that boots all the way up past 'Starting Windows' and then a 'Please Wait' screen, finally to a 'Preparing To Configure Windows - Do Not Turn Off Your Computer' which it sits at for a minute or so then the computer reboots.

I have tried F8 safe mode and 'last known good configuration', which do the same thing.

This is an encrypted laptop, so I cant use the windows 7 install disk to do anything or access the hard drive externally.

I am guessing it's a bad update, but any ideas?

Comment: [See this page](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/192279-reboot-loop-during-preparing-configure-windows-cant-safe-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

boot from the Windows 7 DVD or [Windows Recovery Environment](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11028.how-to-access-windows-recovery-environment-in-windows-7.aspx), open run the command prompt in the repair options

[image]

and run this:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\
```

*(replace C: with the drive where you installed Windows 7)*

This reverts all pending operations. Now you should go back to Windows 7.

Now copy the folder `C:\Windows\logs\CBS` to your desktop, zip it, upload it to OneDrive/Dropbox or any other Cloud FIle sharing service, create a share link and post the link here. I'll take a look what is causing the loop.

Comment: So it makes sense that this is exactly what I need to do, but the problem is as I mentioned the drive is encrypted.   So when I go to the prompt, navigate to the C drive I do not see any files for example.   If there were a way to boot to that dos prompt, by using something like F8 when the normal OS is starting, it would work since the POA has kicked in which kicks in the decryption.

Comment: Does this allow you to unlock the drive? **manage-bde -unlock C: -PASSWORD** Or do you use  3rd party tool instead of Bitlocker?